# Proper way of streaming using ResponseEntity and making sure the InputStream gets closed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-web, request-mapping

One of our application leaks file handles and we have not yet found the cause for this.

In the code I can see several functions similar to this:

```
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFoo( ... ) {
    InputStream content = getContent(...)
    InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(content);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK).body(isr);
}
```

(`if` checks and `try` / `catch` removed for brevity)

I am sure this section causes the problem because when I loadtest this specific code with JMeter I can see that `getContent()` fails in this stage:

```
is = Files.newInputStream(f.toPath());
```

Normally I would close the `InputStream` but because this short and simply code I can't close the stream before `return` or the call of `body`.

When I run `lsof` (the code runs on Linux) I can see that thousands of files are open in read mode. So I am sure this problem is caused by the stream not getting closed.

Is there a best practice code I should trade in ?

Comment: Just a guess, can you check leak happen in HEAD requests or GET?

Comment: As far as I can see this does not happen with `HEAD` only with `GET`

Comment: Ok, my guess was since implicit HEAD will not consume body, it might cause leakage. It's not the case.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

you can try to use StreamingResponseBody

> **StreamingResponseBody**
>
> A controller method return value type for asynchronous request processing where the application can write directly to the response OutputStream without holding up the Servlet container thread.

Because you are working on a separate thread, writing directly to the response, your problem to call `close()` before `return` is solved.

probably you can start by the following example

```
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> export(...) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //...

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/example/file"));


    StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {

        int numberOfBytesToWrite;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while ((numberOfBytesToWrite = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            System.out.println("Writing some bytes..");
            outputStream.write(data, 0, numberOfBytesToWrite);
        }

        inputStream.close();
    };

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=generic_file_name.bin")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .body(responseBody);
}
```

You can also try to use `Files` (since java 7)

so you don't have to manage `InputStream`

```
    File file = new File("/path/to/example/file");

    StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), outputStream);
    };
```

As @Stackee007 described in comment, under heavy load in production environment it's a good practice also to define a `@Configuration` class for a `TaskExecutor` to tune parameters and manage `Async` processes.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncConfiguration.class);

    private final TaskExecutionProperties taskExecutionProperties;

    public AsyncConfiguration(TaskExecutionProperties taskExecutionProperties) {
        this.taskExecutionProperties = taskExecutionProperties;
    }

    //  ---------------> Tune parameters here
    @Override
    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        log.debug("Creating Async Task Executor");
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(taskExecutionProperties.getPool().getCoreSize());
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(taskExecutionProperties.getPool().getMaxSize());
        executor.setQueueCapacity(taskExecutionProperties.getPool().getQueueCapacity());
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix(taskExecutionProperties.getThreadNamePrefix());
        return executor;
    }
    
    //  ---------------> Use this task executor also for async rest methods
    @Bean
    protected WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
                configurer.setTaskExecutor(getTaskExecutor());
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    protected ConcurrentTaskExecutor getTaskExecutor() {
        return new ConcurrentTaskExecutor(this.getAsyncExecutor());
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }
}
```

**How to test with mockMvc**

You can simply follow this sample code in your integration test as:

```
    .andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
    .andDo(MvcResult::getAsyncResult)
    .andExpect(status().isOk()).getResponse().getContentAsByteArray();
```

Content type of `ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>` is a `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` in this example and you can get byte[] (`.getContentAsByteArray()`) but you can get String/Json/plaintext of everything depending of your body response content type.

Comment: This looks promising. Do you want to beef this up a little bit by adding more information ?

Comment: Do heed the note on using StreamingBodyResponse "Note: when using this option it is highly recommended to configure explicitly the TaskExecutor used in Spring MVC for executing asynchronous requests. Both the MVC Java config and the MVC namespaces provide options to configure asynchronous handling. If not using those, an application can set the taskExecutor property of RequestMappingHandlerAdapter."

Comment: added  implementation of a TaskExecutor configuration

Comment: How to test it with `mockMvc` - add
`.andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
.andDo(MvcResult::getAsyncResult)`
to your integration tests. [source](http://digitallumberjack.me/post/test-streaming-springboot/)

Comment: i've written a little example with mockMvc integration test

Comment: Is it possible to use StreamingBodyResponse with Jdk 1.6, i have legacy project that needs to use asynch response streaming.

Comment: Bit of a gotcha with `andDo(MvcResult::getAsyncResult)` - if the `StreamingResponseBody` lambda throws an `Exception`/`Throwable`, the integration test will effectively ignore the exception.

This is longer, but fails the test if there's a problem: `.andDo(r -> { var result = r.getAsyncResult(TIMEOUT_MS); if (result instanceof Throwable e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); } })`

Comment: Another option (probably better) for checking the async result is documented in Spring's javadoc for `MockMvcRequestBuilders.asyncDispatch()`:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#asyncDispatch-org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult-

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you are using Spring, your method could return a [Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) and let Spring handle the rest (including closing underlying stream). There are [few implementations of Resource are available within Spring API](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/AbstractResource.html) or else you need to implement your own. In the end, your method would become simple and would like something like below

```
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFo0(...) {
    return new InputStreamResource(<Your input stream>);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `ResponseEntity` use the `InputStreamResource`, not `Resource`

Answer (score 4):

You could refactor all your controller methods that read local files and set their contents as the body of the HTTP response:

Instead of using the `ResponseEntity` approach you inject the underlying `HttpServletResponse` and copy the bytes of the inputstream returned from your `getContent(...)` method to the outputstream of the `HttpServletResponse`, e.g. by using IO-related utility methods of Apache CommonsIO or Google Guava library. In any case make sure you close the inputstream! The code below does this implicitly by the use of a 'try-with-resources'-statement that closes the declared inputstream at the end of the statement.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFoo(HttpServletResponse response) {
    // use Java7+ try-with-resources
    try (InputStream content = getContent(...)) {

        // if needed set content type and attachment header
        response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=foo.txt");
        response.setContentType("txt/plain");

        // copy content stream to the HttpServletResponse's output stream
        IOUtils.copy(myStream, response.getOutputStream());

        response.flushBuffer();
    }
}
```

reference:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html
https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html

(especially have a look at methods `public static int copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException` and `public static int copyLarge(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException` of class `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`)

Comment: I like @Marged approach (in case it has no caveats I'm not aware of) a little more for its conciseness and as it's possibly more consequent to work with `ReponseEntity` in _all_ endpoints. Nevertheless we've been using Tommy's approach in several applications and it works flawlessy.

Comment: Spring's [FileCopyUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/FileCopyUtils.html) can be used as well - it closes the stream for you so one thing less to remember than IO-related utility methods of Apache CommonsIO or Google Guava library.

Comment: Am I right that the main advantage of `StreamingResponseBody` over using `HttpServletResponse#getOutputStream` is that you can start `TaskExecutor`, so writing data to stream won't [hold up the Servlet container thread busy](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/StreamingResponseBody.html)? I'm just trying to understand what is the difference between those two.

Answer (score 3):

Because this `InputStream` is basically coming from a simple file, a good replacement is this code:

```
FileSystemResource fsr = new FileSystemResource(fileName);
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK).body(fsr);
```

[`FileSystemResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html) can take a `java.util.File`, a `java.nio.file.Path` or even a `String` pointing to the relevant file.

Comment: Does this handle closing of resource and different encodings(like iso lat 1)?